# In Django Admin, I want to change how foreign keys are displayed in a Many-Many Relationship admin widget

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-widget

I have a ManyToMany relationship:

```
class Book:
  title = models.CharField(...)
  isbn = models.CharField(...)

  def unicode(self):
    return self.title

  def ISBN(self):
    return self.isbn

class Author:
  name = models.CharField(...)
  books = models.ManyToManyField(Book...)
```

In the admin interface for Author I get a multiple select list that uses the unicode display for books.  I want to change the list in two ways:
1) Only for the admin interface I want to display the ISBN number, everywhere else I just print out a "Book" object I want the title displayed.
2) How could I use a better widget than MultipleSelectList for the ManyToMany.  How could I specify to use a CheckBoxSelectList instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2), use this in your AuthorAdmin class:

```
raw_id_fields = ['books']
```

Check here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin for instructions on creating a custom ModelAdmin class. I've thought about this a lot myself for my own Django project, and I think 1) would require modifying the admin template for viewing Author objects.

Answer (score 3):

To display the ISBN you could make a custom field like this:

```
class BooksField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.isbn
```

There's a [CheckboxSelectMultiple](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) for the ManyToManyField but it doesn't display correctly on the admin, so you could also write some css to fix that.

You need to create a form for the model, and use that in your admin class:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    books = BooksField(Book.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Author

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('booksfield.css',)
        }

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AuthorForm
```